# In Kotlin how to use the method getTime()

Tags: datetime, kotlin, import

The Kotlin documentation https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/get-time.html says that there exists a method **getTime()**. But do not tell which module to import to use it. I would greatly appreciate to get this information.

Comment: Rather than the JavaScript `Date` that your link refers to I recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import java.util.Date

e.g : `Date().getTime()`

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I don’t think it’s correct and in any case we shouldn’t use it. (1) If from the link from the question you click on [Date](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/index.html) at the top and next on [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it says *JavaScript `Date` objects represent a single moment in time …*. So not `java.util` (2) The `java.util.Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated, I recommend against using it.

Comment: @Ole V.V. I tried to follow your advice : I went to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and I got lost ... Could you please tell me which java package I must import and what syntaxe I should use to get the same result as getTime() in Kotlin ?

Comment: No, sorry, I don’t know more than what it says on those pages. As I said under the question, I’d go for importing and using `java.time` classes, not any `Date` class.